# JHipster prod profile Grunt build error on Eclipse

Tags: gruntjs, jhipster

I'm doing an app with JHipster 1.4.0 using Eclipse.

In dev profile, no problem, but when i switched to prod profile, there's an error in build :

Description : Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: com.github.trecloux:yeoman-maven-plugin:0.2:build (execution: run-grunt, phase: generate-resources)

Resource : pom.xml

Path : /myapp

Location : line 444

Type : Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem

I'm new to Eclipse and i didn't find a solution on forums. If someone can help...

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I just had a same issue, and this was because I had another process using the same port number as Grunt (port 9001).
Can you check your Grunt error message? I had:

```
    Running "connect:test" (connect) task
Fatal error: Port 9001 is already in use by another process.
```

Comment: When running Grunt in command line, there is no problem so the running "connect:test" (connect) task replies Started connect web server on http://0.0.0.0:9001.

The problem i describe is in the maven build in Eclipse.